# External Javascript form validation isn't working, not sure why?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, function, validation

So I have written a Javascript external file which I will put below. It is to validate input in a form in the HTML site/file. I still have more functions to add but won't worry about them until I've got it working correctly. The Javascript code is:

```
// JavaScript source code

function fourDigit(ID)
{
    "use strict";
    var pattern = /^[1-9]\d{0,3}$/g;
    var result = pattern.test(document.getElementById(ID).value);

    if (result == false)
    {
        alert("Please insert a valid numeric value between 1-9999");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

function runner()
{
    "use strict";
    fourDigit('RunnerID');
}

function event()
{
    "use strict";
    fourDigit('EventID');
}

function validate()
{
    "use strict";
    var result = runner() && event();

    if (result == true)
    {
        alert("all good");
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        alert("doesn't work");
        return false;
    }
}
```

When I test this on the HTML file (I call the `validate()` function on the submit button of the form), it always give me the `alert("Please insert a valid numeric value between 1-9999");` and `alert("doesn't work");` even when I insert valid numbers into the RunnerID and EventID form fields. I can't figure out why hence the question. May be something simple but only started learning Javascript recently.

The HTML file I'm calling it in is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC
  "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<title>Submit a runner time</title>
<script language="javascript" src="validate.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<hr/>
<h1>Submit a runner time</h1>
<hr/>
Note: all fields marked '*' are mandatory.
<p/>
<form onSubmit="return validate()"> 
<table>
<tr><td>Runner ID*</td>
<td><input type="text" id="RunnerID" name="RunnerID" size="4" maxlength="4"/></td>
</tr>
<tr><td>Event ID*</td>
<td><input type="text" id="EventID" name="EventID" size="4" maxlength="4"/></td>
</tr>
<tr><td>Date (YYYY-MM-DD)*</td>
<td><input type="text" name="Date" size="10" maxlength="10"/></td>
</tr>
<tr><td>Finish time (HH:MM:SS)*</td>
<td><input type="text" name="FinishTime" size="8" maxlength="8"/></td>
</tr>
<tr><td>Position</td>
<td><input type="text" name="Position" size="5" maxlength="5"/></td>
</tr>
<tr><td>Category ID</td>
<td><input type="text" name="CategoryID" size="3" maxlength="2"/></td>
</tr>
<tr><td>Age grade</td>
<td><input type="text" name="AgeGrade" size="5" maxlength="5"/></td>
</tr>
<tr><td>Personal best</td>
<td><input type="text" name="PB" size="1" maxlength="2"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="submitrunnertime" value="submit"/>
<hr/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: Where are you calling your script ? can you share it

Comment: Yes, sure. It is in the HTML file, in the form line of code which says `<form onSubmit="return validate()">`. Hope that helps

Comment: Can you share your html file code too ?

Comment: please read up on `boolean` so you will not do this anymore: `result == true`

Comment: Just added it now.

Comment: yes, your textfields need `id=` you only state `name=`

Comment: The `fourDigit(ID)` is called in the `runner()` and `event()` functions and they call `fourDigit(ID)` with the ID parameter i.e. `'RunnerID'` and `'EventID'`

Comment: What i can't get it you're taking the values from document.GetElementById() and using name in text field. Am i blind or does javascript introduce something new ?

Comment: @user7262738 Dear if you want to get the value of textbox through id then provide them id or use document.getElementsByName() function.

Comment: Just change document.getElementsById() to document.getElementsByName() and see if that works

Comment: And a one tip too If you want to load your document first then call script below the body

Comment: Ok I added `id="RunnerID"` and `id="EventID"` to the relevant parts which did not work. I got no alerts even when there was no input. Then I tried the getElementsByName and that did not work either

Comment: My last comment, load it at last of your body tag

<script language="javascript" src="validate.js"></script>

Comment: What I don't understand is the function is called and gives an alert properly but when the correct data is input it is like it won't equate to true or give the 'all good' alert. It still says 'insert value' 'doesn't work' yada yada.

Comment: Still getting the same issue after moving the <script> line

Comment: Code updated. Other than the better regex, I've been reverting the code to original when it doesn't work

Comment: I also try updating the DOM path to `document.submitrunnertime.getElementById()` without luck

Comment: I''ve added IDs to the fields and added the `.value` in the JS and now when I input correct numbers in the fields, I don't get the 'insert number' alert, just the 'doesn't work' one so it is obviously passing the regex comparison now, but I think the `validate()` is not equating to true.

Comment: you need to `return  fourDigit('EventID');` in both your methods

Comment: as in @Hezron answer

Comment: Please don't vandalize your post.

Comment: Seriously, stop vandalizing the post.

Comment: I requested it to be removed with good reason. They choose not to

Comment: Requested how?  Either way, when you posted here, you accepted the copyright license of this site.

Comment: **Moderator Note:** Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, it belongs to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license).  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-rout‌​e-for-a-dissociation-request)

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is wrong!

`[1-9999]` means 1 digit number in the range of 1 to 9

You need `^[1-9]\d{0,3}$`

meaning:

`^`: start of string

`[1-9]`: 1 digit from 1-9

`\d`: a number

`{0,3}`: 0 to 3 digits long

`$`: end of string

this will not allow `0111` or any number starting with `0`

Comment: Ok great, I will get to sorting that. Trouble is, the fault is still there for some reason. Thanks

Comment: [1-9999] means 1 digit number in the range of 1 to 9, or the character 9, or the character 9 or the character 9

Answer (score 1):

Pure JS.

```
// JavaScript source code

function fourDigit(ID)
{
    var pattern = /^([1-9][0-9]{0,3})$/;;
    var result = pattern.test(document.getElementsByName(ID)[0].value);

    if (result == false)
    {
        alert("Please insert a valid numeric value between 1-9999");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

function runner()
{
    return fourDigit('RunnerID');
}

function event()
{
    return fourDigit('EventID');
}

function validate()
{
    var result = runner() && event();

    if (result == true)
    {
        alert("all good");
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        alert("doesn't work");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: The trouble is, I think I need to use regex as that is what I've been learning. I appreciate the alternate solution though, thanks

Comment: I think he is not using jquery he needs a javascript solution and you come up with jquery. might be it would be effective too :)

Comment: I update my code with pure JS. And using regex. Try it.

Comment: When I use that, I don't even get the alerts at all although I'm unsure why

Comment: maybe because your input using `name=` as ID, not `id=`. so this `getElementById` is wrong.

Comment: I update my answer using `getElementsByName`. Try it.

Comment: I''ve added IDs to the fields and added the `.value` in the JS and now when I input correct numbers in the fields, I don't get the 'insert number' alert, just the 'doesn't work' one so it is obviously passing the regex comparison now, but I think the `validate()` is not equating to true.

Comment: check my `runner()` and `event()` function, i add `return` inside.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a bunch. The return sorted it. Was a pain in the ass ha but thank you kindly :D